# What do I do with the PayPal public key?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

So what do you use the secret key for ?

I'm developing using WordPress/Php and got a bit annoyed at the various Paypal plugins not doing exacly what I wanted them to, so I wrote my own plugin which works perfectly. I can get any interaction I want within my applications.

I'm using Paypal checkout, but my implementation only uses the public key. Most PayPal plugins I've seen you have to provide both the public and private keys. It just dawned on me that I'm not using the private key.

My question is what do I do with the private key ?

Do I need to use it. I've been through the paypal documentation and although there is lots of documentation about the private key, there is nothing that says you have to use it. Should I be bothered about not using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the REST API `clientid` and `secret`, the secret is used for server-side API communication with PayPal.

If your integration is not doing any server-side API communication with PayPal, then you won't be using it for anything.

Server-side integrations are more robust, and require a developer with the knowledge and ability to implement them. Here is a front-end UI pattern that would communicate with 2 server-side routes: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Those routes would need to be created on the server, and implement the appropriate business logic as well as do API calls to PayPal, using the clientid and secret, to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', respectively.  Here is information on that: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was some of the stuff I'd already read. I'm using the front end UI pattern. Originally I was going to use front end and server, but the front end pattern does everything I need it to do so I never bothered with the server side stuff. Should I bother with that extra step if I don't need to. My requirements don't match any of the use cases :)

Comment: I think you mean you're using the client-side pattern, which is not divided into a front end/backend.  If it meets your requirements then that's what it's there for.

Comment: ah cool thanks. it just got me wondering as I got it working first time which for me is never that easy. I'm using it on client websites just thought I might need to be doing more